# Android permission list with corresponding methods

Tags: android, permissions

Is there any document of list of permissions in android and the names of methods for which these permissions are needed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Refer the document for the [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: This is your best resource since it would be unfeasible to create and maintain a list of all the methods in android and their permissions. New methods are added all the times and permissions are changed or new ones are added as well. In case you are interested in the permissions for a method, a simple Google search is all you need to do.

Comment: For the methods that each permission protects see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24019120/475329

Answer (score 1):

PScout was a tool that analysed Android SDK and generated a map that maps Android permissions to methods.

Original PScout website doesn't work anymore but I extracted the mapping from original PScout and pushed it to Github. You can easily check it out and parse it if you need it.

Here you can find all methods that PScout found which require Android permissions.

[PScout results- map of Android permissions and methods that require those permissions](https://github.com/drag0/pscout_results)