# Android - How do I know all methods that require a certain permission?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions

I work on a project that currently asks for 21 (!) permissions.

I want to clean that up as I believe a lot of them are not necessary (for instance, there is a permission for `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` which can be removed as pretty much the same thing can be achieved with an `Intent` with `ACTION_DIAL`).

What I want to know is a way to, **given a permission (say, `android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`) find all methods which require that permission**.

Note that the opposite is easy, i.e., given a method, it is easy to find if that method requires any permission (just go to the documentation and check), but what about the other way around?

Comment: i was about to say that :)  just go check, after all if you are implementing a function and do not know if there are permissions then hmm .. just saying sir. i don't think there is unless you are willing to use Reflection to check the exceptions they might throw in event of a permission not set and play with it.

Comment: Not exactly the Answer to your question, but may be an alternate Approach can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257412/remove-extra-unwanted-permissions-from-manifest-android/8257473#8257473

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping between Android permissions (that we define in the manisfest file ) to corresponding API calls /methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740632/mapping-between-android-permissions-that-we-define-in-the-manisfest-file-to-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this again, I came across a similar question on SO. Ben Holland explains there are 2 studies done about this problem. None of the solutions proposed are 100% flawless, but it is the best we have so far.

More details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24019120/1369016

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all methods that PScout found which require Android permissions. PScout was a tool that did this particular work you need, but the original website is offline.

[PScout results- map of Android permissions and methods that require those permissions](https://github.com/drag0/pscout_results)

Answer (score 0):

No way else the compiler would warn you if you haven't set a Permission. No, instead the application just crashes on runtime.

Im sorry but you have to go the long way and search for methods that you think might need permissions and delet them